# Does ajax have to wait for a PHP script to finish before displaying the output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to run a simple PHP script which echos numbers. To test if ajax would display each echo as it happens or if it waits for the whole script to finish before displaying anything.

```
<?php 
    echo '1';
    sleep(5);
    echo '2';
    sleep(5);
    echo '3';
    sleep(5);
    echo '4';
    sleep(5);
    echo '5';
?>
```

This has shown me that it does wait for the whole script to finish before displaying the numbers.

I would like to know if it is possible to output each echo as it happens, similar to how you would see it in shell?

Answer (score 0):

No that's impossible as the PHP script must run and return it's output before it is supplied to the AJAX request.

Comment: Or to work with javascript as server-side language as well.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to wait for fractial result. But you can use `websockets` to achieve this behaviour.

For example you can use php library [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) or use `javascript` (or other language) as server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways, techniques and software on how to implement what you need.

Here is a basic and easy example for you: https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

It is based on a long polling technique.

But I would suggest you to use a centrifu-go with sockJs library for a large projects.